# Error while creating the Maven + JSF Project from cmd

Tags: java, maven, jsf

I am very new to Maven, to create JSF + Maven Project i am running the following command.
Can any one help me in this how to create the maven project and JSF should configure in that.

```
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.my-company.my-project -DartifactId=my-project-web -DpackageName=com.company.project.web -DarchetypeGroupId=com.rfc.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=jsf-maven-archetype -DremoteRepositories=http://maven.rodandjen.us/repo
```

following error is getting

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:create (default-cli) on project stand
alone-pom: Error creating from archetype: org.apache.maven.archetype.downloader.DownloadException: Error downloading com
.rfc.maven.archetypes:jsf-maven-archetype:jar:RELEASE. Failed to resolve version for com.rfc.maven.archetypes:jsf-maven-
archetype:jar:RELEASE: Could not find metadata com.rfc.maven.archetypes:jsf-maven-archetype/maven-metadata.xml in local
```

please help in this why i am getting the error.

Comment: Your given repo `http://maven.rodandjen.us/repo` is not online... It seems that your archetype is not available there

Comment: thank you for ur reply , can please suggest me how to create the maven with JSF project from CMD. i am able to create through eclipse but not from  cmd . so please tell me the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this from command prompt,

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

You should see quite a number of default templates and you should find some JSF as well. Enter your desired JSF template number.

After you pick a number for a JSF template, hit enter, it would prompt you for entering Group, artifactId, version and package. Hit enter and your JSF project should be created.